# Any optimized way to make this function work faster?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

```
def getDiff(rows, cols, df1, df2):
for item in zip(rows, cols):
    df1.iloc[item[0], item[1]] = '{} --> {}'.format(df1.iloc[item[0], item[1]],
                                                             df2.iloc[item[0], item[1]])
return df1
```

This function is identifying the differences in two dataframes. This is working fine however, if there are more differences or more records in dataframes this is taking long time.

I am here looking to find any faster way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function would be bit easier to read with:

```
def getDiff(rows, cols, df1, df2):
    for r,c in zip(rows, cols):
        df1.iloc[r, c] = '{} --> {}'.format(df1.iloc[r, c], df2.iloc[r, c])
    return df1
```

or even:

```
def getDiff(rows, cols, df1, df2):
    for item in zip(rows, cols):
        df1.iloc[item] = '{} --> {}'.format(df1.iloc[item], df2.iloc[item])
    return df1
```

But none of this changes speed.  You don't tell us much about the dataframes, but even if they start as numeric dtypes, by writing this string to `df1`, you have turned it into an `object` dtype array.

`pandas` has some string methods that may be applied to whole series, but I'm not familiar with those.